# Get element by class vs multiple get element by id calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

im concerned about selecting multiple elements from page. Is better to use selector by class, or multiple calls selector by id?

Number of elements which i wana select, or trash elements which i dont wana select, but selector must check them is every time different.

(sorry for my english)

Comment: IDs are faster to query, but classes make your code clean. Go for the latter.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: If the elements can be logically grouped with the same class then do that, or if they're all of the same type consider selecting by tag name, otherwise use id.

Comment: It's better to use class in this case because you are not sure if you only have one element. If you're going to work on that collection, store it in an obj and do your work on that obj so jQuery doesn't have to search the DOM multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should use what is most readable. For this situation, it would be selecting by class name - which turns out to be more performant as well. In the future, it is best to avoid micro optimizations like these because they are more than likely not going to affect performance one way or the other. It is important to identify when performance will be a factor, and that usually comes in when your script is taking more than 100ms to execute.

***[`jsPerf Demo`](http://jsperf.com/by-class-versus-many-by-id)***

jsperf is great for these types of questions

html

```
<div>
 <div class="divs" id="a1"></div>
 <div class="divs" id="a2"></div>
 <div class="divs" id="a3"></div>
 <div class="divs" id="a4"></div>
 <div class="divs" id="a5"></div>
 <div class="divs" id="a6"></div>
 <div class="divs" id="a7"></div>
 <div class="divs" id="a8"></div>
</div>
```

get element by class script

```
var divs = $(".divs");
```

get element by id in a loop

```
var divs;
for( var i = 1; i < 9; i++ )
{
 divs == void 0? $("#a"+i) : divs.add($("#a"+i));
}
```

Results:

by class:

```
109,735 opts/second
±4.17%
fastest
```

in loop by id:

```
75,074 opts/second
±5.70%
33% slower
```

Comment: I tried jsperf on my real data, and id seems like better option. Results are here [link](http://jsperf.com/class-vs-id-search)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a bunch of elements is better to use a selector by class. When you use a Selector by id is because  you just want to use that element. The ID should be unique.

Spanish answer:
Los selectores si quieres traer varios elementos deberia ser utilizado por clase. Si utilizas por id se supone que en el html solo deberia de haber un elemnto con un Id es unico.